# Why clojurescript macros can't be written in clojurescript?

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

While clojure and clojurescript features are basically the same (apart from obvious differences), macros are not. When I want a macro in clojurescript I have to write it in clojure and require it with require-macros. Is that a technical limitation of javascript or just a design decision? Why can't both be the same?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

From [ClojureScript: Up and Running](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920025139.do) by Stuart Sierra and Luker VanderHart, page 69:

> Macros are applied during the compilation process. They do not exist
>   at runtime. Because
>       the ClojureScript compiler is implemented in Clojure, ClojureScript macros must be written
>       in Clojure, not ClojureScript. Fortunately, Clojure and ClojureScript are almost identical
>       when it comes to manipulating data structures, so switching between the two languages is
>       not difficult.

What that means is that macro code gets executed in Clojure world and not in the browser, so it must be written in plain Clojure.

Comment: And it's that way because clojurescript uses the google closure compiler I imagine... A clojurescript compiler written in clojurescript would be nice.

Comment: Google Closure Compiler is only used to removed unused dependencies and minify the code, not to compile ClojureScript to JavaScript. When the code reaches Google Closure Compiler is already just JavaScript, though the ClojureScript team works hard making sure the JavaScript produced is valid for most advanced Google Closure Compiler features.

Comment: On a related note, there is work being done on a ClojureScript to ClojureScript compiler at [clojurescript.net](http://clojurescript.net/). One of the authors discusses it in [this video](http://www.infoq.com/presentations/cljs-in-cljs).