# In Clojurescript, how to write a dbg macro that does really nothing when in production mode?

Tags: macros, clojure, clojurescript

In `Clojurescript`, I would like to write a `dbg` macro like the one below, but with a **tweak**: I want this macro to simply return `x` when in production mode (like we used to do with `C` macros).

Is it possible to achieve that? How the code of the macro could detect production mode -- at **compile** time)?

```
(defmacro dbg[x]
  `(let [x# ~x]
     (.log js/console (str '~x ": " ~x))
     ~x))
```

Your help is appreciated.

Comment: I wouldn't go in this direction. THe advanced compilation will remove dead code and filter out everything. You can emit code that wraps it in a if. For instance goog.assert does it like that and all asserts are removed during adv. compilation.

Answer (score 1):

If you compile javascript on production server you can use `(System/getenv)` to get env variable and decide if it's production or not.

Add to `~/.bashrc` on production server:

`export ENV=production`

and in clojurescript macro:

```
(if (= (System/getenv "ENV") "production")
    (.log js/console ...))
```

Comment: Are you sure this is working? Being a ClojureScript question, I would expect that the target runtime is NodeJS, which does not have `System`.

Comment: @Kineolyan clojurescript targets browser and nodejs. See https://clojurescript.org/guides/quick-start

Comment: Exactly my point. Your code will never work in a browser or NodeJS. It only works in a JVM

Comment: You are correct, compiler will run in jvm. Clojurescript compiles to javascript using jvm. If you want to compile for production specify `ENV=production` and debug code will not be included in javascript.

Comment: so sorry. I was not aware that clojurescript macros were not executed at runtime, even for such a code - ref: [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18381849/3252477). So I competely agree with your solution. Can we include this detail in your answer for beginners like me who forget this key point?