# How to use clojure.tools.macro/name-with-attributes in ClojureScript?

Tags: clojure, macros, lisp, clojurescript

I would like to give a name to a macro and I can do it in Clojure with this method **clojure.tools.macro/name-with-attributes**.

What is the equivalent method in **ClojureScript** ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately you can only define macros in Clojure, not in ClojureScript. But once defined, you can use them in both.

As explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18381849/4782314), macros are applied at compilation. And because the compiler is written in Clojure, macros must be implemented in Clojure as well.

Hope this helps.